# How are dividends taxed if there is no wage income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, investing

Based in USA.

How are dividends taxed if an individual does not have wages from labor?

Comment: Why does it matter whether or not you have wages from labor?

Comment: Do you have other taxable income? Capital gains and dividends taxation is based on that number, taxable income, regardless of source. If you edit to add details, you'll get a decent answer.

Answer (score 2):

The same way other income - business income, Social Security benefits, IRA withdrawals &c - is taxed.  After filling out any needed forms or worksheets, you put the amount on the appropriate line on your form 1040 (lines 3a & 3b for dividends), then add up lines 1-7 to get your taxable income.

Reading the instructions is always a good idea :-)

PS: Just for example, I haven't had actual wage income (that is, reported on a W2) in maybe 15 years.  I still have to file tax returns just like most people.  The only difference is that I leave the wage income line blank.

Answer (score 1):

'Qualified' dividends have a special [tax rate](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/taxes/dividend-tax-rate/). Separately, [you may not need to file](https://www.hrblock.com/tax-center/income/other-income/how-much-do-you-have-to-make-to-file-taxes/) if you and/or your household have an extremely low income.

You might want to use tax software to see what it comes up with for your situation.

Comment: That link also mentions that one might be required to file for other reasons. Having enough dividends despite having little or no wage income would probably be one of those reasons. Having more than the minimum income means you must file; having less does *not* mean you don't.

Comment: Please add something on the difference between Qualified and Non-qualified dividends, and how Non-qual dividends are taxed.

Comment: @RonJohn: When you get your 1099-DIV statement(s), they will have figures for ordinary and qualified dividends.  There's no need for the ordinary taxpayer to understand the difference, and indeed, doing a bit of searching has convinced me that it's not really possible unless you're a tax accountant.